# Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have 2 managed object contexts: (1) created as `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` that is used by the UI/main thread and (2) created as `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` that is used by the networking. Both of these contexts go to the persistent store (i.e., I'm not using parent/child contexts).

For the view controller, I'm using a `UITableViewController` with a `NSFetchedResultsController` that uses the 1st UI managed object context.

I am merging changes from the 2nd managed object context into the 1st context by observing the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

The app works fine until it processes a network response that causes a new object to be inserted **and** an existing object to be deleted in the 2nd context. When the 2nd context is saved, the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` fires and the changes are merged into the 1st context. The delegate methods of `NSFetchedResultsController` are invoked and a new row is added to the table, but the row representing the deleted object is **not* removed.

If I attempt other actions on the table view, like reloading the table or updating other objects, I get this assert in the console log:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:],
/SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -
controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in
section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the
update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
from that section (6 inserted, 6 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows
moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with 
userInfo (null)
```

Typically, you get this error if you've forgotten to update your model objects when using `UITableView`'s batch update methods, but in this case, `NSFetchedResultsController` is doing all work. My delegate methods are boilerplate:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
  switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
  NSLog(@"    didChangeObject type=%d indexPath=%@ newIndexPath=%@", type, indexPath, newIndexPath);

  UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

My UITableViewDataSource `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  }

  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}
```

And `configureCell:` is:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Event *event = (Event *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text = [[event valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Owner"];
  NSArray *objects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [objects.lastObject name]; // simplified
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` gets terribly confused if you use an `NSFetchRequest` when preparing your cell in response to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. If you don't execute a `NSFetchRequest`, all is well. However, if you do, it triggers `NSFetchedResultsController` to perform further change notifications, which does bad things to `UITableView`.

The workaround for this is to set `includesPendingChanges = NO` on your NSFetchRequest.

I have opened a radar issue about this -- problem id `14048101` -- with a detailed example and sample app. This bug reproduces on iOS 5.1, 6.0, and 6.1.

In my sample app, I added logging to Xcode's CoreData template to log enter/leave of `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods. When I insert + delete objects on the network context, the logging shows:

01: => (before) mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification
02:   => (enter) controllerWillChangeContent count=4
03:   <= (leave) controllerWillChangeContent count=4
04:     didChangeObject type=1 indexPath=(null) newIndexPath= 2 indexes [0, 0]
05:   => (enter) controllerDidChangeContent count=5

At this point, all is good. `controllerDidChangeContent:` has been called to process the 1 insert, which calls `[tableView endUpdates]`, which calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which calls `configureCell:atIndexPath:`.

06: => (enter) configure cell at row 0

At this point, `configureCell:atIndexPath:` creates an `NSFetchRequest` and calls `[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]` -- here begins the badness. Executing this fetch request triggers the processing of the remaining changes in the context (1 delete and 3 updates) before processing of the insert has finished (we entered `controllerDidChangeContent:` on line #05 and don't leave until line #16).

07:   => (enter) controllerWillChangeContent count=5
08:   <= (leave) controllerWillChangeContent count=5
09:     didChangeObject type=2 indexPath= 2 indexes [0, 4] newIndexPath=(null)
10:     didChangeObject type=4 indexPath= 2 indexes [0, 2] newIndexPath=(null)
11:     didChangeObject type=4 indexPath= 2 indexes [0, 1] newIndexPath=(null)
12:     didChangeObject type=4 indexPath= 2 indexes [0, 3] newIndexPath=(null)
13:   => (enter) controllerDidChangeContent count=4

At this point, the framework is making a re-entrant call to`controllerDidChangeContent:`.

14:   <= (leave) controllerDidChangeContent count=4
15: <= (leave) configure cell at row 0
16:   <= (leave) controllerDidChangeContent count=4
17: <= (after)  mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

At this point, you can see in the UI that: (1) a new cell has been added, (2) 3 cells were updated, and (3) the deleted cell is still visible, which is wrong.

After further action in the UI, I typically get an `Assertion failure` or message sent to an invalid object exception.

My sample app is available at https://github.com/peymano/CoreDataFetchedResultsController

Comment: This is it! I arrived at this answer after looking at many many different questions that relate to this error. This is the only one that helped provide understanding of what's going on with my issue. If any of you have this issue, either use the workout mentioned, or you can possibly solve this issue by using a relationship instead of  a seperate fetch request from within the configurecell method. This really helped me out, thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more about a "using a relationship" from within the configuredcell method?