# UITableView swipe to Delete row in tableview getting error like -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:],

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I swipe to delete a row in my UITableView, I get an error like this:

```
-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:],
```

```swift
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [ArrCartitem removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try removing the item from your data source before deleting the table row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905935/assertion-failure-in-uitableview-endcellanimationswithcontext-with-nsfetche refer this

Comment: First delete data from Array

Comment: Nice cool working Thank you Dan